# Parsing Log File in R

Tags: regex, r, logging

I am quite new to R. I am trying to parse some weblogs in order to do some analysis. So far I can pull out the usernames, dates and application (everything that is fixed width) but I want to pull out the information that the person is looking up which is slightly more unstructured.

```
raw_data <- c('2014-08-06 09:00:27554swomey                       SingleCustomerView                                                                   name=JOHN, nameEntity=JOHN, ppsn=1234567C, address1=123 Fake Street, dob=11/11/1911,',
'2014-08-06 09:00:30302swomey                       SingleCustomerView                 327FF1F4AFF3EE7C2C6334072CDE1401                  execution=e1s1, ',
'2014-08-06 10:01:38648agnolan                      SingleCustomerView                                                                   address1=123 FAKE STREET, dob=11/11/1911, name=JOHN SMITH, nameEntity=BLAH, ppsn=1234567E, ',
'2014-08-06 10:01:39552agnolan                      SingleCustomerView                 C3D63A0B53A43BBBDB7F76E55E906D74                  execution=e1s1, ')

splitdata <- data.frame(date=substr(raw_data,0,22), username=substr(raw_data,23,52), 
                    application_name=substr(raw_data,53,87), session_id=substr(raw_data,88,137))
```

What would be the best approach to pull out the other information such as name, nameEntity, ppsn, address etc bearing in mind each variable might not be in everyline.

I tried something along these lines but am getting confused. I assume I need to use an apply function?

```
x <- "name=JOHN, nameEntity=JOHN, ppsn=1234567C, "

pattern <- "ppsn=(\\w+)"

match   <- regexec(pattern, x)
words   <- regmatches(x, match)

match
words
```

Many Thanks.

Edit: Apologies the log file actually looks like this with commas inside of the address line so spliting by commas isn't as easy.

```
raw_data <- c('2014-08-06 09:00:27554swomey                       SingleCustomerView                                                                   name=JOHN, nameEntity=JOHN, ppsn=1234567C, address1=123 Fake Street, Dublin, Ireland, dob=11/11/1911,',
'2014-08-06 09:00:30302swomey                       SingleCustomerView                 327FF1F4AFF3EE7C2C6334072CDE1401                  execution=e1s1, ',
'2014-08-06 10:01:38648agnolan                      SingleCustomerView                                                                   address1=123 FAKE STREET, CORK, IRELAND, dob=11/11/1911, name=JOHN SMITH, nameEntity=BLAH, ppsn=1234567E, ',
'2014-08-06 10:01:39552agnolan                      SingleCustomerView                 C3D63A0B53A43BBBDB7F76E55E906D74                  execution=e1s1, ')
```

Comment: What are you expecting for the result if we use the `raw_data`?

Comment: Exactly as hrbrmstr just replied below. Sorry for not including in orginal post.

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting log format. If you want a data frame back, this should work (there are a couple ways of doing it...this splits strings vs processing regex capture pairs):

```
res <- lapply(raw_data, function(x) {

  # get the unstructured/variable bits

  info <- gsub(",\ *$", "", substr(x, 137, nchar(x)))

  # and process them

  lapply(unlist(strsplit(info, ",\ +")), function(y) {

    # return name/value pairs in a list

    fields <- unlist(strsplit(y, "="))
    ret <- list()
    ret[[ fields[1] ]] <- fields[2]
    ret

  })

})

# make a data frame from them, filling in missing bits with NA

rbind.fill(lapply(res, as.data.frame))

##         name nameEntity     ppsn        address1        dob execution
## 1       JOHN       JOHN 1234567C 123 Fake Street 11/11/1911      <NA>
## 2       <NA>       <NA>     <NA>            <NA>       <NA>      e1s1
## 3 JOHN SMITH       BLAH 1234567E 123 FAKE STREET 11/11/1911      <NA>
## 4       <NA>       <NA>     <NA>            <NA>       <NA>      e1s1
```

You can just `cbind` this back with what you processed from the fixed-width fields.

Comment: Thanks very much. 

Wouldn't you know it is never that easy though... I am after realising that there are commas inside the address line now. There must be a way to exclude using the strplit function on the address field 

address1=81 A OAK DRIVE, WAY HILL, BLAH, DUBLIN, dob=11/11/1911,